# DistributedCacheService Consuming A lot of memory SP2013

Tags: app-fabric

The Distributed Cache on our WFE is consuming too much memory (50% of the server, almost 6GB out of 12GB)

It seems like we have AppFabric 1.1

along with the other services it's consuming 95% of the server

i suspect the AppFabric is the problem because only the Search service has a higher consumption too (1.4GB)

how can I troubleshoot if we have a problem with the AppFabric, release its memory or configure it for a lower consumption.

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is expected. How many concurrent users do you have utilizing the farm? You can use `Update-SPDistributedCacheSize` (https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sharepoint-server/update-spdistributedcachesize) to lower the allowed memory usage but if you set it too low, you may run into performance issues.

[Plan for feeds and the Distributed Cache service in SharePoint Server](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/administration/plan-for-feeds-and-the-distributed-cache-service)

[Manage the Distributed Cache service in SharePoint Server](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/administration/manage-the-distributed-cache-service)

Comment: Thanks Trevor, 
I Think our server is OK, the memory allocation looks steadily on the 50% but we've noticed that with time it will release some memory, also the server doesn't hang or degradates so we will leave it as is